# Unity gameobject going into terrain.2

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, gameobject, terrain, collider

My problem is that my car goes in to the terrain. I have the colliders and triggers, this is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKD66-uh6U4) with my car.

Comment: Notice your Z axis is changing as you move.  You need to check your code to see if you are altering this.  Try to see if you can lock the Z axis for your object.

Comment: using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour { public float speed = 20; public float turnSpeed = 45; public float horizontalInput; public float forwardInput; private Rigidbody rb; // Start is called before the first frame update void Start() { rb = GetComponent(); }

Comment: // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

     transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed*forwardInput);
     transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime *horizontalInput);

     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
     {
         rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
     }else
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
     {
         rb.AddRelativeForce(-Vector3.forward * speed);
     }
 }
}

Comment: It's tricky not being able to see the whole project but I would try these two options and see if either work.  Since you don't want to move on the z axis, you could could use a vector2 `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.forward * speed);`.  Another option would be in the Rigidbody of your car object, under constraints, freeze the z axis on both rotation and position.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but it doesen't work, it's still getting into terrain with both your options.